# how to count elements in google spreadsheets matching a certain date range

Tags: google-sheets

I have some data in columns with a timestamp in the first column and data columns.

```
A             B         C         D
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
20.5.2011     1         2         5
18.5.2011     3         5         4
12.5.2013     4         7         5
```

I am able to successfully filter columndata based on the timestamp with this google spreadsheets formula. The below returns a sum of all integers in column B if there is a corresponding 2011 timestamp.

```
=ArrayFormula(SUMIF(TEXT($A:$A;"yyyy");year(today())-1;$B:$B))
```

the above sums up the values 1 and 3 from column b and returns 4

The question is, how would I calculate the average for the above values 1 and 3 resulting in 2? My current approach is to divide the above formula by the count() of items that match the date criterion but I cannot get it to work.

```
=ArrayFormula(SUMIF(TEXT($A:$A;"yyyy");year(today())-1;$B:$B))/WFORMULA FOR THE DIVISOR
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use COUNTIF in much the same way as you used SUMIF:

`=ArrayFormula(SUMIF(TEXT($A:$A;"yyyy");YEAR(TODAY())-1;$B:$B)/COUNTIF(TEXT($A:$A;"yyyy");YEAR(TODAY())-1))`

(this would currently return the average of all the 2012 entries).

You can simplify this a little by using the YEAR function in the comparison array:

`=ArrayFormula(SUMIF(YEAR($A:$A);YEAR(TODAY())-1;$B:$B)/COUNTIF(YEAR($A:$A);YEAR(TODAY())-1))`

You can also generate a table of sums, averages or counts quite easily with QUERY:

`=QUERY(A:B;"select year(A), avg(B) where A is not null group by year(A) label year(A) 'Year', avg(B) 'Average'")`

and if you just wanted the average for 2012 as a single value:

`=QUERY(A:B;"select avg(B) where year(A) = "&(YEAR(TODAY())-1)&" group by year(A) label avg(B) ''")`